# concurrent.futures does not throw exception when using try except

Tags: python, exception, concurrent.futures, try-except

When using `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor()` it doesn't throw an exception for `try except`.

For eg:

```
num = [1,2,3,4,5]
def div():
    for i in num:
        return i/0
    print('Done')

try:
    div()
except:
    print('Not Divisible by 0')
```

The above code prints the `except` part but the below code doesn't

```
num = [1,2,3,4,5]
def div(i):
    return i/0

try:
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        executor.map(div, num)
    print('Done')
except:
    print('Not Divisible by 0')
```

Comment: get the results from the executer and then will see the exception. something like this `try:
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        results=executor.map(div, num)   
    for result in results:
        print(result)
    print('Done')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`executor.map` does not raise the exception right away. Instead that exception will be raised when the value is [retrieved from the iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Executor.map). For example try this,

```
>>> num = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>>
>>> def div(i):
...     return i/0
...
>>> import concurrent.futures
>>>
>>> with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
...     result = executor.map(div, num)
...
>>> result # Not evaluated yet
<generator object Executor.map.<locals>.result_iterator at 0x0000019E60A36570>
>>> list(result) # This will raise the `ZeroDivisionError` exception
```

So to get the expected behavior, evaluate the return value of `executor.map` within the try block.